# virtual address space and physical RAM

Tags: memory, ubuntu-12.04, virtual-address-space

On Ubuntu, when I look at meminfo, I notice that the virtual address space total is much greater than the physical ram total:

```
/proc $ cat meminfo
MemTotal:        6113156 kB
...
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
```

I thought that virtual address space directly maps to RAM address space. So how could this be so much larger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processor keeps a virtual page to physical page mapping.  This is true.

Since an exception occurs (meaning the kernel is called) when a process tries to access memory in a page it shouldn't, the kernel can take advantage of this fact to swap in a page stored on disk, and then resume the process where it left off, instead of just segfaulting the process.

So in this way, you can have a swapfile that has pages that have actually been "swapped out" of RAM entirely and don't live in RAM.  This isn't really part of the hardware design of the MMU, but it involves the kernel physically doing the swap behind the scenes of the userspace process.

Comment: But look how big that number is: 34359738367. That is 32767 gigabytes of memory right there. I don't even think the machine has that many gigs on disk, let alone gigs reserved for swap space on disk.

Comment: I think things like `mmap` - which some programs use to read files, and which is basically the operating system making a file look like it's in memory and swapping bits around on demand - can ask the kernel to allocate virtual memory addresses, even though they won't ever be used to swap processes.  Do you have a large database running on this system?  I heard also ZFS uses a lot of virtual address space if you happen to be using that on FreeBSD or similar.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I have apache2, phusion passenger, ruby on rails, a ruby daemon, redis server, juggernaut server installed on this system. I have mysql client program installed but the database itself is on another machine. No databases on this machine.